# run a .exe remotely via psremote

Tags: powershell

I want to run a .exe file which is installed on ten servers remotely via PowerShell or psremote. The .exe file is on the same path on all servers.
I have tried this command for only one server: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock {get-item -path c:\myexefile.exe}` but didn't work for me. I have the ports used by psremote opened.
The error is: "Connecting to remote server Server1 failed with the following error
message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer
name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall
exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer........"

Comment: Have you enabled Powershell remoting ? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Hello, yes ps-remote is enable, and it is working properly.